# My dropdowns won't work after I exported the gridview to excel file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have a dropdown called `company` and a button called `export to excel` and a gridview, also I have an update panel for both controls but when I export to excel dropdown won't work anymore, even if a want to export 2times I cannot without refreshing the page.

My export code:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      // HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
           "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Kontratat-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls"));
       HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";


       StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
       HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


       HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
       hw.WriteLine("<center><b><u><font size='5'>Kontratat</font></u></b></center>");//will be displayed in excel as a heading.
       GridView1.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
       frm.Controls.Add(GridView1);
       frm.RenderControl(hw);
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
       HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

   }
```

and my aspx code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
```

help me please

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0):

I think returning an XLS file in the code that should render the content of an update panel is not a good solution. Why don't you redirect to a new page that contains the code of your button click as page_load? This way a whole new page will generate the file, the browser will ask to save it and it will automatically redirect then to your principal page. Can you try that way?